# Multiple Select drop down list how to save selected value to database using jquery ajax form submit (codeigniter)

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, multi-select

I am using jquery ajax to submit my form , i am having a multiple select drop down list which i am selecting and saving the values to database basically all selected values are saved in database but while i am retrieving the values in view only one value is comming.

```
<div class="form-group ">
<label class="control-label col-lg-2">Location</label>                
<div class="col-lg-2">
<select class="form-control" id="city"   onChange="getArea(this.value);">
<option value="">- Select Location -</option> 
<?php  foreach($city_tuitor as $rom) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $rom->city_id; ?>"> <?php echo $rom->city_name; ?>        </option>
<?php  } ?>      
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
<select class="form-control" id="area" name="area" multiple>
<option value="">- Choose Area -</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This is my script where i am posting value to my modal as i am new to this thats why i am not sure i am doing it in a right way or not

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add_searchagent").click(function(){

var city = $("#city").val();
var area = $("#area").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString =  'city='+ city + '&area='+ area  ; 
//alert (dataString);
//die;
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Tutor/searchagent",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
location.reload();
//alert("Added Succesfuly");
}
}); 
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

This is modal where i am inserting values to database

```
public function add_searchagent()
{

$city=$_POST['city'];

//if(isset($_POST['area'])) $area=implode(",",$_POST['area']);
//$area=implode(',',$_POST['area']);
$area=$_POST['area'];
$data = array(
   'city_id' => $city,
   'area_id' => $area
);
//print_r ($data);
$this->db->insert('search_agent', $data); 
echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";
}
}
```

And this is the view where i am trying to get all area values but i am only getting first value of area .

```
<?php 
foreach($search_agent as $agent){
?>
<tr>
<td>City:</td>
<td><?php echo $agent-> city_name; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Area</td>
<td>
<?php
echo $agent-> area_name;  ?>                      
</td>
</tr>
<?php } <?PHP
```

Retriving from view

```
public function search_agent_view()
{
$tutor_name = $this->session->username;

$this->db->join('city_tuitor', 'search_agent_tuitor.city_id = city_tuitor.city_id');
$this->db->join('area_tuitor', 'search_agent_tuitor.area_id = area_tuitor.area_id');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('search_agent_tuitor');
$this->db->where('tutor_name', $tutor_name);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $search_agent = $query->result();

}
```

Comment: you mean inserted successfully in database but problem in retriving?

Comment: yes values are inserting successfully i can show you by print_r its like this Array
(
    [city_id] => 1
    [area_id] => 1,2,3,4 //these are the values
)
Form Submitted Succesfully

Comment: basically i am not sure i am doing it in the correct way or not :(

Comment: okey where is your query from where you are retrieving results

Comment: public function search_agent_view()
{
$tutor_name = $this->session->username;
$this->db->join('city_tuitor', 'search_agent_tuitor.city_id = city_tuitor.city_id');
$this->db->join('area_tuitor', 'search_agent_tuitor.area_id = area_tuitor.area_id');

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('search_agent');
$this->db->where('tutor_name', $tutor_name);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $search_agent = $query->result();

}

Comment: wait i will post that in code view

Comment: please check i have posted it

Comment: any idea @DivyeshSavaliya

Comment: What's a tuitor, and how does it differ from a tutor ?

Comment: both are same i don't think problem is because of that , is that creating any problem ? @Strawberry